# Iterate python dictionary to assign value to table's fields

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Using an API I get a json dictionary as response in the form:

```
{"transacDet":[{"field1":6933434802,"field2":323499903,"field3":293483842},
{"field1":693433448,"field2":333400300,"field3":298334300}],"responseStatus"
:{"statusMessage":"success","statusCode":0}}
```

I am looking to create records in a table having the same corresponding fields as in the json response: field1, field2, field3.

From the above example I would have 2 records:

```
field1 = 6933434802
field2 = 333400298
field3 = 298334842
```

and then:

```
field1 = 693433448
field2 = 333400300
field3 = 298334300
```

I have to iterate the response but not clear how.

I try using:

```
for k in resp_json.items()[0][1][0]:
print k
```

but I'm stuck there.
TIA

Comment: do you want to write those fields into DB?

Comment: What is the expected output? A printed table where your fields appear in columns, and one row per record?

Comment: I think the aim is to know how to iterate, what will be output is a detail he will implement on his own (in my understanding). Cf. eg my answer for having keys of the fields and the values accessible in a loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need indeed to assign those values to fields in my database. something like 
` INSERT (field1, field2, field3) ` 
and then on the next iteration again the same 
` INSERT (field1, field2, field3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only json module from standard library you can iterate over them sorted by field names per "row" easily like so:

```
#! /usr/bin/env
from __future__ import print_function
import json


JSON_TEXT = '''
{"transacDet":[{"field1":6933434802,"field2":323499903,"field3":293483842},
{"field1":693433448,"field2":333400300,"field3":298334300}],"responseStatus"
:{"statusMessage":"success","statusCode":0}}'''

resp_json = json.loads(JSON_TEXT)
for d in resp_json['transacDet']:
    for k in sorted(d.keys()):
        print(k, d[k])
```

Which yields:

```
field1 6933434802
field2 323499903
field3 293483842
field1 693433448
field2 333400300
field3 298334300
```

**Update** to sketch how one could push these values into an INSERT call:

```
# inside the loop instead of iterating over the fields in the
# dict / row at hand, one could easily for instance do:
resp_json = json.loads(JSON_TEXT)
for d in resp_json['transacDet']:
    insert_row(**d)
```

Here insert_row would be a function defined as follows (sample):

```
def insert_row(**kwargs):
    """Not production ready ;-)."""
    # pick up the row key-value pairs from dict
    list_of_tuples = [
        (k, kwargs[k] for k in sorted(kwargs.keys())]
    pass  # here you might use this list of (k, v) tuples
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need indeed to assign those values to fields in my database. 
something like 

   ` INSERT (field1, field2, field3) `

and then on the next iteration again the same 

   ` INSERT (field1, field2, field3)`

Comment: I updated the answer to give an idea how one might plug in a function and then there (after validation of input values) perform a real prepared insert or the like. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
a= {"transacDet":[{"field1":6933434802,"field2":323499903,"field3":293483842},
{"field1":693433448,"field2":333400300,"field3":298334300}],"responseStatus"
:{"statusMessage":"success","statusCode":0}}

import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame(a['transacDet'])

df
Out[11]: 
       field1     field2     field3
0  6933434802  323499903  293483842
1   693433448  333400300  298334300
```

iterate the dataframe:

```
for i in df.iterrows(): print i[1], '\n'
field1    6933434802
field2     323499903
field3     293483842
Name: 0, dtype: int64 

field1    693433448
field2    333400300
field3    298334300
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

So if you don't want use `pandas`. just use generator (list comprehension), this is based on @Dilettant 's solution:

```
[(k, d[k]) for d in resp_json['transacDet'] for k in sorted(d.keys())]
Out[24]: 
[(u'field1', 6933434802L),
 (u'field2', 323499903),
 (u'field3', 293483842),
 (u'field1', 693433448),
 (u'field2', 333400300),
 (u'field3', 298334300)]
```

Comment: Why would you import `pandas` just to handle this simple case?

Comment: My motivation to provide a plain answer was spurred by this using pandas answer, but on the other hand, I have simply forgotten, when in my life I learned to not do everything on an atomic lavel. So good to have this implicitly heavy solution side by side with the other more explicit standard solutions. The OP seems to simply want to learn how to iterate over heterogenous structures in python as a beginner, and thus I think the other answers are more illuminating along that way. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Dilettant, yes, you are right, for the purpose of learning, `pandas` is not a good choice, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By what I understad, you just to iterate the `transacDet` key:

```
import json
parsed = json.loads('{"transacDet":[{"field1":6933434802,"field2":323499903,"field3":293483842}, {"field1":693433448,"field2":333400300,"field3":298334300}],"responseStatus" :{"statusMessage":"success","statusCode":0}}')

for record in parsed['transacDet']:
    print record
```

Result:

```
{u'field2': 323499903, u'field3': 293483842, u'field1': 6933434802}
{u'field2': 333400300, u'field3': 298334300, u'field1': 693433448}
```

Then you can send it wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

I assume `resp_json` is already a `dict`.

So, to access the list of field `dict`s, you would reference it by the key, not the index:

`resp_json['transacDet']` provides you with:

`[{"field1":6933434802,"field2":323499903,"field3":293483842},
{"field1":693433448,"field2":333400300,"field3":298334300}]`

You would then want to iterate through those, like so:

```
for values in resp_json['transacDet']:
    # here you can now access the content of the current `dict`
    print 'field1 = ' + values['field1']
    # would print: "field1 = 6933434802"
    # ... and so on
```

Comment: I think as this is a list of dicts where the keys in these dicts are the seeked field names, the above access to ` values['field1']`will not work.

Comment: Not sure I follow your comment. This does in fact work - could you clarify?

Comment: Ah, my bad, tried to look at it through the eyes of the OP, and this is not always my best mode of operation. **But** assuming the OP is only at the beginning of learning Python, this access pattern might in fact irritate, as only field1 is picked, and it has to be known upfront (at least in the sample) so in my understanding of the question, it is especially a simple "pick them all" per row / dict solution that he wanted to see. But I may be wrong here. So your code of course "works" but only accesses the values of "filed1" per row.

Comment: Read the inline comments. The assumption is that the OP understands the pattern and can implement for all fields. If the goal is to in fact learn then blindly giving a solution would be counter productive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a= {"transacDet":[{"field1":6933434802,"field2":323499903,"field3":293483842},
{"field1":693433448,"field2":333400300,"field3":298334300}],"responseStatus"
:{"statusMessage":"success","statusCode":0}}

import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame(a['transacDet']).T

print df[0]
print df[1]



 #  field1    6933434802
  #  field2     323499903
  #  field3     293483842
  #  Name: 0, dtype: int64

  #  field1    693433448
  #  field2    333400300
  #  field3    298334300
  #  Name: 1, dtype: int64

import json

JSON_TEXT = '''
{"transacDet":[{"field1":6933434802,"field2":323499903,"field3":293483842},
{"field1":693433448,"field2":333400300,"field3":298334300}],"responseStatus"
:{"statusMessage":"success","statusCode":0}}'''

resp_json = json.loads(JSON_TEXT)


t1 = [[k,v] for k,v in  resp_json['transacDet'][0].iteritems()]
t2 = [[k,v] for k,v in  resp_json['transacDet'][1].iteritems()]      

 print (t1)
 print (t2)

   # [[u'field2', 323499903], [u'field3', 293483842], [u'field1', 6933434802]]
   # [[u'field2', 333400300], [u'field3', 298334300], [u'field1', 693433448]]
```